# Understanding License information in the "Installed Licenses" feature

Tags: sitecore-client, licensing

For some time, Sitecore has included an "Installed Licenses" feature which can be reached by navigating to *Start -> All Applications -> System -> Installed Licenses*, by clicking the hamburger button in the Content Editor (for Sitecore 8+; in older versions, click the Sitecore logo in the Content Editor instead) and selecting "Licenses".

It is my understanding that, by default, Sitecore ships with an entry for every official Sitecore module that they provide that is licensed to the solution via the installed License file. Since Sitecore does not, by default, keep a record of the versions of installed modules, I was hoping to extend this feature to display that information, at least for official modules, but I would be fine with adding extra entries, if needed (even for offical modules that should already have an entry).

## Question

My question has the following four parts:

1. **What is the *actual* purpose of this feature, if different from my understanding?**
2. **What do the `Count` and `Version` values actually represent?** The screenshots, below, depict these values for the `Sitecore.WFFM` entry of a clean Sitecore 8.2.1 instance without WFFM installed and a Sitecore 7.2.0 instance that has WFFM installed. Notice that the values are the same regardless of whether or not WFFM is actually installed. While not shown, note that the values `Count: 1` and `Version: 8` are actually the same for *nearly all* of the module entries, not just the `Sitecore.WFFM` entry, including `Sitecore.xDB.Base`, `Sitecore.SXA` and more. The value is different for the `Sitecore.SiteUser` entry which is set to the maximum amount of concurrent users that my license allows, the `Sitecore.MSS.Sites` entry, the `SiteCore.EditorUser` entry (title copied verbatim; it has the capital "C" for "SiteCore", like `SiteCore.Runtime` and `SiteCore.SQLConnector` in the screenshots, below), the `Sitecore.Domain` entry, and the `SiteCore.Developer` entry (also copied verbatim).
3. **Is there any way to extend/update an entry to display additional comments/version information without modifying the installed license file?**
4. **Is there any way to add an entry to this list for a custom module/feature without modifying the installed Sitecore license file?**

## Site-Note

I am aware that newer (Sitecore 8+) versions of the "Installed Licenses" dialog have the caption:

> Click a license to view the terms and conditions.

and that for older versions the caption is:

> Here is a list of all the licenses that are contained in your license
>   file. To view the terms of a license, click it.

However, since the terms of these licenses are not auto-populated in the entries and the content of the entries is not editable, I recognize that my understanding of the purpose of this feature may not be correct.

## Screenshots

**Sitecore 8+** (screenshot depicts a clean Sitecore 8.2.1 instance without WFFM installed)

[image]

**Older Versions** (screenshot depicts a Sitecore 7.2.0 instance with WFFM installed)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This couldn’t the final answer to your queries but some analysis from my end, worth reading :)

**Update in License File:**

Whenever Sitecore official module is installed into an instance, below changes are included/appended in license file. (/data/license.xml)

*- Snapshot:*
 Name,Expiration,count,version & license agreement are appended under `<signature>` node of a module in license file and the same is retrieved to display in licensedetails page. 
*note: License agreement might not appear for partner license.

[image: License info & Module info]

**License Overview Page:**
Page which list all the sitecore official modules when selected from 'Installed Licenses'.

*License overview url is:* `http://<yourinstancename>/sitecore/shell/applications/licenses/licenseoverview`

*snapshot:*

[image: overview page]

*Physical path of xml file:* 
`<physicalpath>\Website\sitecore\shell\Applications\Licenses\LicenseOverview\LicenseOverview.xml`

*Codebehind:*
`Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Licenses.LicenseOverview.LicenseOverviewForm from Sitecore.Client.dll`

**License Details Page:**
Module's License detail page which list 6 fields coming out from signature node of a module in license file.
*License Details Page url is:*

```
`http://<yourinstancename>sitecore/shell/Applications/Licenses/LicenseDetails.aspx?name=[ModuleName]
```

*Snapshot:*

[image: module's license details]

*Physical path of xml file:* 
`<physicalpath>\Website\sitecore\shell\Applications\Licenses\\LicenseDetails\\LicenseDetails.xml`

*Codebehind:*
`Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Licenses.LicenseDetails.LicenseDetailsForm from Sitecore.Client.dll`

**Conclusion:**
Finally i think adding certain fields into modules manifesto information & retrieving it in license details window couldnt be an easy task to do. :(

Comment: Thanks, Balaji! That's really interesting that you got the license agreement details. In truth, the screenshots that I took were of solutions running on a Partner License, so perhaps that is why the details didn't display.